# TFS 2010 Single Server Install. Reporting Service Guidance needed

Tags: tfs

They changed our domain password expiration policy recently. Now the TFSReports service account password is invalid and Report Server won't start. Have I missed any steps in this "fix it" plan?

1. Login to server as TFSSetup account  (which has not yet expired!)
2. Change password of the Windows Service account TFSReports
3. Restart Reporting Services under Windows Service
4. Open TFS Admin console, Application Tiers, Reporting Services Summary, then
   select "Update password" and do the deed.
5. Reboot the server

Other than the new password in step 4 is there any other info that will be required for entry?

Comment: An upgrade to TFS 2018? 2010 is end-of-life.

Comment: yes, just wish to update the TFSReports password

Answer (score 0):

To change the password of the TFSReports account, you must log on to a server that hosts the application services for Team Foundation and use the **TfsConfig Accounts** utility:

1. Open a Command Prompt window and change to the directory that contains the **TFSConfig** utility.

By default, the utility is located in `Drive:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Tools`.

2. At the command line, type **`TFSConfig Accounts /UpdatePassword /accountType:ReportingDatasource /account:AccountName /password:newPassword`**, and then press ENTER.

More information, please refer to this site: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552344(v=vs.100)